# Передать параметры программе и получить результат

Tags: c#

Есть консольная программа которая принимает на вход несколько параметров. login и password. Как с помощью c# передать параметры?

Comment: Учитесь формулировать мысли. Перечитайте свой вопрос, поставьте себя на место того, кто его читает. Из вопроса я, например, могу сделать такой вывод:

Вариант 1:
Есть некая программа готовая уже, которая принимает логин и пароль, возможно через формочки оконные, возможно через веб-интерфейс, возможно в консоле или ещё где-то. Ещё у нас есть язык С#, и надо написать программу, которая передаст первой программе логин и пароль.

Comment: Вариант 2:
Есть код на С#, который представляет собой не то веб приложение, не то консольное, не то оконное, и нужно, чтобы эта программа считала 2 строки, в формах, в консоли или, может, как параметры командной строки...

Уффф...

Comment: Я думаю, теги должны были подсказать, о чем речь. Есть консольная программа, которая принимает на вход параметры.

Comment: @Mehelta пишите, пожалуйста, вопросы более конкретно.

Answer (score 3):

**Обновил по результатам обсуждения:**

```
using System;

class TestClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string login = args[0];
        string password = args[1];
    }
}
```

аргументы командной строки, при условии запуска программы из консоли так:

```
program.exe vasya 123456
```

Comment:     string login = args[1];
    string password = args[2];

@iksuy вы так получите IndexOutOfRangeException/ нумерация индексов массива начинается с 0

Comment: @DreamChild, args[0] == "program.exe", разве нет?

Comment: Боюсь, что нет. Сейчас проверил - выкидывает исключение. Код таков: 

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
                Console.WriteLine(args[1]);
                Console.WriteLine(args[2]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();  
        }

результат: ![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/0CmnNTF.png

Comment: @DreamChild, спасибо, думал, что в С# заполнение аргументов аналогично С/C++.

Answer (score 0):

Если Ваш вопрос о том, как написать такую пограмму, то см. ответ [@iksuy](/users/13597/iksuy). Я бы к нему добавил, что метод `Main` должен быть либо без возвращаемого значения (`void`), либо возвращать `int` - код возврата, который Вы передаёте системе после выполнения программы.

Если же Вам нужно вызвать готовую программу, передав ей логин и пароль, то Вам нужно использовать `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(string fileName, string arguments)`. Этот метод запустит процесс через `fileName`, передав запущенной программе параметры через `arguments`. Он вернёт экземпляр класса `Process`, у которого есть метод `WaitForExit` и свойство `ExitCode`. Дождитесь завершения программы и прочитайте `ExitCode`.

Answer (score 0):

вот так можно передать параметры и скрыть

```
 Process myProcess = new Process();
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("RUN");

            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            //SAME
            //myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath;
            //OR THIS
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Application.StartupPath + "\\" + "your_app.exe";
            myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-param1 -param2 param3 param4";
            myProcess.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS");
        }
        catch (Exception eS)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(eS.Message);
        }
```

передача параметров через пробел