# C# Приложение с входными и выходными параметрами

Tags: c#

Подскажите, пожалуйста: например

Запуск приложения ->
Указываем строковое значение ->
Работа приложения ->
Получаем строковое значение

Т.е. есть цель создания некоего модуля, который бы мог использоваться разным софтом с указанием некоторых входных данных и получением в зависимости от этого результата. К примеру указали приложению ссылку на сайт , получили результат, есть ли там указанный текст - получили `true`/`false`.

Вопросы:

- можно ли это сделать в консольном приложении?
- если да то как принимать и как отправлять значения?
- другой вариант?

Comment: Вопрос состоит в чем?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/382900/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В других ответах уже написали про параметры командной строки и код возврата.

Но, как мне кажется, вам больше подойдут [стандартные потоки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8) ввода-вывода и их [перенаправление](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0).

Например, напишем такую простейшую консольную программку:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Читаем из стандартного потока ввода
        string line = Console.ReadLine();

        // Обрабатываем введенное значение
        line = line.ToUpper();

        // Пишем в стандартный поток вывода
        Console.WriteLine(line);        
    }
}
```

Кстати, можно явно писать `Console.In.ReadLine()` и `Console.Out.WriteLine()`, указывая потоки ввода и вывода.

Если её запустить, то нужно будет ввести строку в консоли. Результат тоже появится в консольном окне.

Теперь можно использовать перенаправление потоков. Например, подадим на вход нашей программе текстовый файл, из которого она прочтёт значение (одну первую строку). Вывод перенаправим в другой текстовый файл.

```
app < in.txt > out.txt
```

Где `app.exe` - имя нашей программы. `in.txt` - входной файл. `out.txt` - выходной файл.

Про конвейер и поток ошибок почитаете сами.

Answer (score 2):

Отвечаю на вопрос, как его понял я :)

Вероятно, вы хотите, чтобы ваше консольное приложение запускалось с некими параметрами (`ping localhost`, где localhost - параметр)

Создайте консольный проект, посмотрите на заголовок главного метода:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

Массив args - это и есть входные параметры.

Если сделать так:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args[0] == "print")
                Console.WriteLine(args[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

А потом скомпилировать, и в командной строке набрать `ConsoleApplication1 print hello` - в консоль выведется `hello`

Дальше сами :)

Answer (score 2):

В [ответе выше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/588700/222168) вам дали код, [даже два раза](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/588705/222168) (повторять его не буду), как принимать параметры командной строки и обрабатывать их в консольном приложении. 
Суть сводится к тому, что вы вызываете свое приложение, и в строке вызова передаете их приложению через строковый массив `args`.

После того, как вы получили нужные параметры, в вашем примере - имя сайта, ваше приложение выполняет необходимые действия и завершает работу. При завершении работы можно указать целочисленный (`int`) код возврата, он же [ExitCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.environment.exitcode(v=vs.110).aspx), который может быть обработан в вызывающем приложении. Т.е. `true` или `false` как вы хотите, возвратить не получится, а вот 0 или 1 (или еще какое число типа `int`) — запросто.

Возвращать можно переопределив метод `Main()` в консольном приложении, заменив `void` на `int`, например так:

```
static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Hello! I'll try to write command-line arguments.");  
        foreach (var parameter in args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Parameter " + i.ToString() + " is: "+args[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();

        return args.Count();
    }
```

В данном коде программа может получать на вход какие-то аргументы командной строки, и пытается вывести их на экран консоли, после чего завершает работу с кодом возврата, равным числу аргументов.

Кроме этого, получить тот же результат (завершение приложения с кодом возврата) можно при помощи метода `Environment.Exit(code)` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.environment.exit.aspx)), которое позволит завершить работу не только по окончанию метода `Main()`, но и из другого места в программе.
Можете попробовать вместо `return args.Count();` написать так: `Environment.Exit(args.Count());` (только верните назад `void` вместо `int`).

Немного модифицированным и более гибким вариантом для решения вашей задачи будет использовать некий буфер (или буферы) для обмена данными, например, файлы:
запускаем программу и в качестве аргумента командной строки передаете ей имя файла с какими-то входными данными, и имя файла, куда будет выведен результат.
Программа обрабатывает входные данные, с их учётом выполняет какие-то действия, а результат записывает в нужном виде в выходной файл, который потом можно обработать как вам захочется.

Для работы с файлами в арсенале C# есть разные инструменты, и рассказывать о всех возможностях как записать/прочитать файл слишком долго и много, но почитать об этом можно, например, [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx), или [тут](http://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/5.3.php), или [здесь](http://mycsharp.ru/post/21/2013_06_12_rabota_s_fajlami_v_si-sharp_klassy_streamreader_i_streamwriter.html). Или [погуглить](http://google.gik-team.com/?q=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D1%81%20%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%20c%23) и найти еще источники )