# как "поймать" данные из консоли?

Tags: c#, вывод, ввод

Незнаю как "ловить" сообщения которые выводит консоль.

Хочу сделать так чтоб один поток писал вывод в консоль, а другой "ловил" сообщения из консоли  и также выводил в консоль слегка измененное сообщение :3

**Как ловить выведенные данные из консоли ??**

вот код :

```
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;

using System.Collections;
using System.Globalization;


namespace trimtram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Terminal()
        {
            for (; ; )
            {
                for (int i = 0; i<1000; i++) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Ввод чепушильных слов {0}.", i);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000); // чтоб не так часто выводил
                }
            }

        }
        static void Lovitel()
        {
            // вот тут мы ловим то что пишет "первый"(Терминал) поток  

            // как это сделать ????
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Тестовая прога.");
            Console.WriteLine("Пытаемся словить \"терминал\" на сишарп.");
             //  в одном потоке создаём сообщения
            new Thread(() => Terminal()).Start();
            // в втором потоке ловим сообщения 
            new Thread(() => Lovitel()).Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну, сделайте буфер вывода на консоль, через него и ловите.

Comment: Имхо, тут следует использовать producer/consumer, в частности - pipeline. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/794380/184217

Comment: @ГеннадийП как сделать буфер на консоль ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо  @AlexanderPetrov за [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput?view=netframework-4.8)

*Помогло :3*

**Вот пример:**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

    public class Test
    {
      public static void Main()
      {
        // создаем процесс "терминал" с параметрами "ifconfig "
        ProcessStartInfo psiOpt = new ProcessStartInfo("ifconfig");
        // скрываем окно запущенного процесса
        psiOpt.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        // настраиваем процесс 
        psiOpt.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psiOpt.UseShellExecute = false;
        psiOpt.CreateNoWindow = true;
        // запускаем процесс
        Process procCommand = Process.Start(psiOpt);
        // получаем ответ запущенного процесса
        StreamReader srIncoming = procCommand.StandardOutput;
        // выводим результат
        Console.WriteLine(srIncoming.ReadToEnd());
        // закрываем процесс
        procCommand.WaitForExit();
        // вводим одну клавишу и закрываем программу 
        Console.ReadKey();
      }
    }
```

**Вот вывод:**

```
dima@komp:~/mita/TCP_IP$ mcs lovla_terminal2.cs 
dima@komp:~/mita/TCP_IP$ mono lovla_terminal2.exe 
eno1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 50:46:5d:6f:da:ba  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xf7200000-f7220000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Локальная петля (Loopback))
        RX packets 82006  bytes 6003526 (6.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 82006  bytes 6003526 (6.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.41  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::49c3:4320:6ca9:3849  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 50:3e:aa:60:a1:34  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1408812  bytes 1912231031 (1.9 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 808121  bytes 115067922 (115.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


mdima@komp:~/mita/TCP_IP$
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, могу предложить задать консоли собственный поток вывода. В нём можно сделать любую обработку данных.

Полный пример приложения:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Terminal()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ввод чепушильных слов {0}.", i);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            var previousWriter = Console.Out;
            var interceptor = new WriterInterceptor(Console.Out);
            Console.SetOut(interceptor);

            var t = new Thread(Terminal);
            t.Start();
            t.Join();

            // Возвращаем на место стандартный поток вывода
            Console.SetOut(previousWriter);
        }
    }

    public class WriterInterceptor : TextWriter
    {
        private TextWriter _baseWriter;
        public WriterInterceptor(TextWriter baseWriter)
        {
            _baseWriter = baseWriter;
        }
        public override Encoding Encoding => null;

        public override void WriteLine(string value)
        {
            value = value.Replace("5", "пять");
            _baseWriter.WriteLine(value);
        }

        // Здесь перегрузки остальных методов Write...
    }
}
```

В данном примере второй поток не нужен.

Конечно, нужно перегрузить все методы вывода TextWriter'а, которые будут использоваться.

Comment: @Увы но вся суть именно "ловить" то что выводит компьютер в терминале и отправлять этот результат на другой компьютер. По сути потоки это разные компы

Comment: @timob256 - почему в вопросе написано совсем другое? Написали бы сразу, что именно нужно. См. [RedirectStandardOutput](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @timob256 - Возможно, вам вообще не нужен код на C#, а достаточно использовать перенаправление стандартных потоков ввода-вывода: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/588873/184217