# Ввод команды в консоль другого процесса

Tags: c#

Сразу скажу что я очень плохо знаю C# и возможно это глупый вопрос, но сейчас потребовалось написать простую программу и возникла проблема решение которой не смог нагуглить.

Вопрос: Могу ли я ввести команду (НЕ запросить ввод типа Console.WriteLine) в консоль другого
работающего процесса ?

Comment: Перенаправление потоков ввода-вывода не поможет? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/588873/184217

Comment: Спасибо большое, Andrew, не знаю как правильно тебя тегнуть, спустя много усилий получилось то что нужно но использовал ещё Process.GetProcessById() и MainWindowTitle и получилось то что нужно было.

Comment: Процесс запущен вами или отдельно до старта приложения? Покажите код запуска консольного процесса.

Comment: Процесс запущен мною вручную до старта приложения. Проблема решена, лучшим решениям может быть только вариант ввода текста не через SendKeys.SendWait а через другую функцию которая бы могла быстрее вводить текст в консоль.