# Можно ли получать данные из процесса в реальном времени на C#? И если можно то как?

Tags: python, c#, процесс

У меня написана программа на python которая парсит сайт и сразу создаёт базу данных с этими данными. из этой проги я сделал exe файл и запускаю его следующим образом:

```
process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject2\\dist\\main\\main.exe";
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.Start();
```

Вывожу данные вот так:
`process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);process.BeginOutputReadLine();`

И ещё вот так пробовал:

```
StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput;
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = reader.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
process.WaitForExit();
```

И еще было несколько странных вариантов. В принципе вывод вроде работает, но в программе на python после каждой странички которую она спарсила через print выводится счетчик (`print(f"Спарсил {all_links.index(link) + 1} страниц...")`), который должен так же выводится и при запуске этого скрипта из C#. Но в действительности я просто жду пока сайт допарсится полностью, а потом получаю все выводимые данные разом.

***Дак вот вопрос. Как мне динамически получать выводимые данные из процесса и сразу выводить их в консоль или куда угодно ещё, а не ждать завершения этого процесса до конца?***

Comment: А не проще перенаправлять потоки ввода-вывода? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/588873/184217

Comment: Примеры перехвата https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1086544/373567, https://stackoverflow.com/a/63541090/12888024

Comment: Ну и проблема кажется в этом https://stackoverflow.com/a/230774/12888024